# How to test Slate JS behavior in Cypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cypress, slatejs

How can I insert text in a Slate editor with Cypress? The Slate `onChange` handler doesn't seem to be called while typing with `cy.type()` or `cy.clear()`.

Answer (score 7):

The Cypress input commands (e.g. `cy.type()` and `cy.clear()`) work by dispatching `input` and `change` events - in the case of `cy.type()`, one per character. This mimics the behavior of a real browser as a user types on their keyboard and is enough to trigger the behavior of most application JavaScript.

However, Slate relies almost exclusively on the `beforeinput` event (see here https://docs.slatejs.org/concepts/xx-migrating#beforeinput) which is a new browser technology and an event which the Cypress input commands don’t simulate. Hopefully the Cypress team will update their input commands to dispatch the `beforeinput` event, but until they do I’ve created a couple of simple custom commands which will trigger Slate’s input event listeners and make it respond.

```
// commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('getEditor', (selector) => {
  return cy.get(selector)
    .click();
});

Cypress.Commands.add('typeInSlate', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, text) => {
  return cy.wrap(subject)
    .then(subject => {
      subject[0].dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('beforeinput', { inputType: 'insertText', data: text }));
      return subject;
    })
});

Cypress.Commands.add('clearInSlate', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  return cy.wrap(subject)
    .then(subject => {
      subject[0].dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('beforeinput', { inputType: 'deleteHardLineBackward' }))
      return subject;
    })
});

// slateEditor.spec.js
cy.getEditor('[data-testid=slateEditor1] [contenteditable]')
    .typeInSlate('Some input text ');

cy.getEditor('[data-testid=slateEditor2] [contenteditable]')
    .clearInSlate()
    .typeInSlate('http://httpbin.org/status/409');
```

If you need to support other inputTypes, all of the inputTypes supported by Slate are listed [in the source code for editable.tsx](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/16ff44d0566889a843a346215d3fb7621fc0ed8c/packages/slate-react/src/components/editable.tsx#L249)

Answer (score 0):

As of Cypress v5.5, this now works as expected! No hacks should be required to make it work with Slate.

See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7088.